# Chart Horizontal Stacked Bar in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, charts

I want to make chart horizontal stacked bar in angular, I already to try with chart-horizontal-bar but its not working, if only chart-bar its working. the below is my code

this is my html code

```
<canvas class="chart chart-bar" chart-type="type" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options" chart-colors="colors" chart-legend="true" chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride"></canvas>
```

this is my js code

```
$scope.statuses = ["Permanent", "Contract", "Probabition", "Out Source", "Grand Total"];
      $scope.series = ['SMA/SMK', 'D1,D2,D3', 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'Grand Total'];
      $scope.dummy = [1, 2, 3, 4]

      $scope.educations = [];

      for (var i=0; i < $scope.series.length-1; i++){
        $scope.educations.push([$scope.series[i], $scope.dummy[0]+i, $scope.dummy[1]+i, $scope.dummy[2]+i, $scope.dummy[3]+i, $scope.dummy.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0)+i])
      }
      
      $scope.labels = $scope.statuses.slice(0, 4);
      $scope.type = "horizontalBar";
      $scope.options = {
        legend: {
          display: true,
          position: 'right'
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        }
      };

      $scope.data = [];
      $scope.colors = ['#4D5360', '#949FB1', '#97BBCD', '#97BBCD', '#97BBCD'];

      for(var i=0; i<$scope.series.length-1; i++){
        $scope.data.push([$scope.dummy[0]+i, $scope.dummy[1]+i, $scope.dummy[2]+i, $scope.dummy[3]+i])
      }
```

Comment: Are you using chartjs?

Comment: yes, I using chartjs, is there an alternative package? @saravanapriyan

Comment: Did you try `indexAxis: 'y'` in options?

Comment: yes, but not working @saravanapriyan

Comment: What chartjs version are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.2.1 version @saravanapriyan